# Exchangeable random variables and identically distributed

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables), we know *exchangeable* is stronger than *identically distributed*. But I am still not sure what this *identically distributed* means. For example, if $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is exchangeable, is it true that $$(X_i, X_j) \overset{d}{=} (X_m, X_n)?$$

Comment: Hint: If $$(X_i, X_j,X_m,X_n) \overset{d}{=} (X_m, X_n,X_i,X_j)$$ then $$(X_i, X_j) \overset{d}{=} (X_m, X_n)$$

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wiki article on exchangeable variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables), the distribution is the same from the definition of *exchangeable* random variables (you only permute a finite number of values).

Comment: Do you mean I can use a coordinate map to show it holds from definition?

Comment: @CHRIS not sure what you need a coordinate map for. The definition allows interchanging any finite sequence for any other finite sequence.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What I mean is the following: from definition, we know (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = (x_i1, x_i2, ..., x_in) in sense of distribution. There are n-arguments. But now I only need the property for 2 arguments.